# Is io.spring.dependency-management plugin required when using Spring Boot 2.3+ and Spring Cloud?

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle, spring-cloud, gradle-plugin

I'm using Gradle 6.6 to build my Spring Boot app. According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60013831/1706691), the io.spring.dependency-management plugin is no longer needed since Gradle 5+ supports BOM files.

However, I receive the following error if I remove the plugin:

```
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.6.1-bin.zip'.
Build file 'C:\my-app\build.gradle' line: 14
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'my-app'.
Could not find method dependencyManagement() for arguments [build_6e8ejdhnd2no2m9jw221sctmn3$_run_closure2@432e46e2] on root project 'my-app' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

Line 14 of my build.gradle file is referenced in the above error. Here are lines 14-18:

```
dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.SR8"
    }
}
```

Is there another way to specify the required dependencies for Spring Cloud without using io.spring.dependency-management plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dependencyManagement()` is provided exclusively by the `io.spring.dependency-management` plugin. Which means you cannot use it if you don't use the plugin.
And in that case you have to use the gradle's `platform` capability.
In the post you linked there's an example of that.

To fix your build, remove the `dependencyManagement` part and add

```
implementation platform("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:Hoxton.SR8")
```

to your `dependencies { }`

Reference: https://docs.spring.io/dependency-management-plugin/docs/current/reference/html/#dependency-management-configuration-dsl

Comment: The Spring Dependency Management plugin also aims to provide the same set of dependencies and versions as what Maven Dependency Management would produce. 
Gradle processing of a BOM follows slightly different rules.